# Make horizontal view with two query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL query and I would like to transform the result horizontally in view.
The first query give the result below :

```
    Id        Point     Label
---------- ---------- ----------
     1          11       'A'
     1          12       'B'
     1           9       'D'
     2          15       'B'
     2           8       'C'
     2           3       'D'
```

The second query give me this result :

```
   Label
---------- 
    'A'
    'B'
    'C'
    'D'
```

The objective is to make a view with the structure below :

```
    Id         'A'        'B'       'C'         'D'
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1         11         12        -1           9
     2         -1         15         8           3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation(column list has to be known in advance):

```
SELECT id,
     COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN Label='A' THEN Point END),-1) AS A,
     COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN Label='B' THEN Point END),-1) AS B,
     COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN Label='C' THEN Point END),-1) AS C,
     COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN Label='D' THEN Point END),-1) AS D
FROM tab
GROUP BY id;
```

Assuming that tuple(Id/Point/Label) is unique, otherwise you could use `SUM` instead of `MIN`.